# Trouble connecting to Ubuntu server using ssh

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh, telnet

I been having trouble connecting to my Ubuntu 18.10 server using ssh. Whenever I try to connect with my college network this is the output

```
    ssh -vvv root@my.server

    OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018
    debug1: Reading configuration data /home/tintin/.ssh/config
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname my.server.ip is address
    debug2: ssh_connect_direct
    debug1: Connecting to my.server.ip [my.server.ip] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /home/tintin/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
    debug1: identity file /home/tintin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/tintin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/tintin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/tintin/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/tintin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/tintin/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/tintin/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/tintin/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/tintin/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
```

And then it completely hangs and nothing else appears. I tried using other ports like 443, 80 but with no better result than the previous one. I even tried to reboot the server but with no results again.

This is the telnet output

```
   telnet my.server.ip 22

   Trying my.server.ip...
   Connected to my.server.ip.
   Escape character is '^]'.
   SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.7p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
   Connection closed by foreign host.
```

But there's no problem connecting to the server from other networks. Is there any way to connect to my server using this college network?

Edit:
As far as I could gather while surfing the net for this problem is that the problem basically resides in the network. So is there anyway to bypass this security feature ?

Answer (score 0):

Strange that it does say connection established. If you had the port wrong it wouldn't establish a connection. Port 22 is the standard. Other servers try not to use port 22 for security reasons (because 22 is the default), like some may use 6922 or something. It's one shot to make sure you are supposed to connect over port 22 (or if it's worked in the past).

My next thought is that some server admins do not allow root access over SSH for security reasons. I'd try getting ssh to maybe the /www folder and seeing if that works. Wish I had better ideas.

Comment: I surfed through the internet a bit more and got to know that there are other people too who faced the same sort of issues and the reason is that their network won't allow ssh on any port. I have really no idea what to do to bypass this security measure. Different people faced the same problem but no one could give a proper solution to this problem.

And thanks for your suggestion but that doen't work either. I tried connecting to other servers, tried other users but with no result at all. Guess I have to use the web console for accessing the server or use another network completely.

Answer (score 0):

After much surfing over the topic finally solved the issue. In this the network administrator is blocking any sort of ssh connection over the network so it's not a problem related to which port I'm using for ssh.

The only solution that I found is to use a VPN and everything would be okay.